# Object properties get lost on $.ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm uploading a large data set as JSON via $.ajax, and some properties get lost during this upload. For the testing purpose, the server returns the first row, where a property is missing.

### javascript

```
function parseResults(data) {
    var send = [];
    for (var x in data) {
        var row = data[x],
            code = row["ORDER"];
        if (typeof code === "undefined") continue;
        if (code == "") continue;
        var temp = {
            code: code,
            date: row["CREATED DATE"] + " " + row["CREATED TIME"],
            pt: row["PAYMENT_CODE"],
            loc: row["LOCATION"],
            fv: row["ORDER VOLUME"],
            fpdf: row["DELIVERY FEE"],
            fpsf: row["SERVICE FEE"],
            vsf: row["REST. SERVICE FEE"],
            pr: row["PAY RESTAURANT"],
            to: row["TOTAL ORDER"],
            delc: row["ORDER PROVIDER"],
            city: row["City"],
            vp: row["VENDOR PROVIDER"],
            rest: row["VENDOR"],
            vouch: row["VOUCHER AMOUNT"],
            cust: row["CUST CODE"],
            st: row["STATUS"]
        };
        send.push(temp);
    }
    sendResults(send);
}

function sendResults(data) {
    for (var x in data) {
        if (data[x].code == "m0sq-p0yq") {
            // this one is here just for testing
            // purposes, you will see
            console.log(data[x]);
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ordersfp/process",
        data: {
            data: data
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }, "json");
}
```

### php

```
public function handleProcess()
{
    $data = Input::all();
    foreach ($data['data'] as $row) {
        if (!isset($row['cust'])) {
            return $row;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

So everything works like it should, the only problem is that this particular element with code `"m0sq-p0yq"` loses property `cust` somewhere.

[image: Console Log of this object]

Besides, I just noticed that `st` property is also lost -.- Please, help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax request is not encoding the data in JSON format, therefore it's trying to send your complex data structure as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. The `"json"` argument in your `$.ajax` call does nothing.

jQuery's [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) accepts either:

- first argument as a URL string, second argument a settings object
- first argument a settings object, no further arguments

Change the ajax to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ordersfp/process",
    data: {
        data: JSON.stringify(data) // encode to JSON
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

On the PHP side, decode the JSON:

```
$data = Input::all();
$decoded = json_decode($data['data']);
foreach ($decoded as $row) {
```

Comment: It works this way, thanks. Although I still don't get why would some properties be ignored by the server (they are present in the post data). So "json" option should also be omitted, I guess?

Comment: Yes `"json"` should be omitted – forgot to remove it. Those pieces of data are most likely not present in the POST data at all, you're logging the object, which will always show all data because it's before the browser tries to process it. The browser doesn't know what to do with complex structures unless you encode in JSON. It's better to look at the Network tab in dev tools and observe what's actually sent to the server.

Comment: I did look in the actual request, and it was present in the POST data, I just didn't take a screenshot. I don't want to reproduce this request, since I've already changed the code based on your answer (had to change much of php code due to the fact that `$row` became an object instead of an array). But Safari showed that `data[58][cust]` (or whatever the index was) was present in the submitted POST data. Thanks anyway!